# Inside celery Task Class run method get task_id

Tags: celery, celery-task

I am trying to run following code:

```
class myTask(Task):
    def run():
        print myTask.request.id
```

But this code is giving None as request_id.
Please Explain me why i am not able to read id in side celery Task Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access request object on class not object instance. Try this:

```
class myTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.request.id
```

You can also use `@task` decorator:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task(bind=True)
def myTask(self):
    print self.request.id
```